# Installed GLIB on MacOS using Homebrew but "... GLIB could not be found"

Tags: homebrew, glib, macos-mojave

I tried to update my glib as part of flex, both installed using Homebrew on 10.14. However, when I config/make my flex project, I get:

```
*** The glib-config script installed by GLIB could not be found
*** If GLIB was installed in PREFIX, make sure PREFIX/bin is in
*** your path, or set the GLIB_CONFIG environment variable to the
*** full path to glib-config.
```

I assume the problem is that last bit, so I did...

```
export GLIB_CONFIG=/usr/local/lib/glib-2.0/include
```

And get the same error. I also tried adding /glibconfig.h to the end, but that does the same.

Looking in config.log I see a different issue:

```
configure:1696:10: fatal error: 'glib.h' file not found
```

I assume the two are related of course, but I'm thinking the root issue is the later. Does anyone know where this file is and what envar it might be using to find it?

Comment: Try `find /usr -name glib-config`

Comment: Try also `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` which you pretty much always need for **homebrew**.

Comment: locate and find both return nothing

Comment: locate glib.h returns a path, but what would I use that with?

Comment: Ok, maybe try `brew ls --verbose flex` and/or `brew ls --verbose glib` to see where all the files installed by each are located.

Comment: Oh, that is very useful. It appears homebrew installed an entirely separate version and the vars have to point to that. I'm not sure what the entire var set is though, but I'm working my way through it one by one.